# Based on User Country/IP address show the SharePoint 2013 Search Results

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-search

We have multiple country documents, Once the search hit from "Africa" user, It should show the "Africa" based documents on top of the SharePoint search results.

Our ultimate goal is top results should match the current user country based.

Answer (score 0):

Good solution is to use Metadata column with tags to tag your documents. Here is the nice article (in the second part of it) about that type columns [Create metadata in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/create-metadata-sharepoint/)

Then you can use Refiners webpart on your search results page to show only needed countries doucments in results [Add refiners in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/stage-15-add-refiners-for-faceted-navigation-to-a-publishing-site)

Comment: Current State: Currently we have applied exactly which you mentioned above. The documents are tagged using metadata column. In the search results using refiner we can choose the country to filter the results.



Expected State: Once the user hit the search from "Canada", the Canada documents should be on the top of the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve this solution by adding a User Profile property that indicates the Users country of origin. Then in your query rule add a refinement that equates the Document Country of Origin to the user like:
`CountryOfOriginn:{User.CountyOfOrigin}`

Comment: It will be working for Intranet. In my case its public facing site.

Comment: Oh, OK I am sorry I missed that you were on-prem. It should still work fine. Unless your users are anonymous. (But I wouldn't recommend using SharePoint for that.)